# kivy objects and memory location

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I've got a Dropdown widget defined in my kv file like

```
<CustomDropDown>:
    myadd_curve_button: add_curve_button
    MyButton:
        id: add_curve_button
        text: 'Add Curve'
```

I'm told that kivy will put a `Dropdown`'s child defined in the kv file into the `Dropdown`'s container. In my app I'd like to loop through the children in the `Dropdown`'s container and be able to catch the child defined in the kv file. But the `is` statement and the memory locations are confusing me:

```
def reset_children(self):
        print(f'button address with id(): {id(self.myadd_curve_button):x}')
        print(f'child address with id:() {id(self.container.children[0]):x}')
        print(f'self.myadd_curve_button: {self.myadd_curve_button}')
        for child in self.container.children:
            print(f'child: {child}')
            if not( child is self.myadd_curve_button):
                self.remove_widget(child)
                del child
```

where `reset_children()` is a method of the `CustomDropDown` class defined in python. The confusing part is the output:

```
button address with id(): 7f9bd5b62bd0
child address with id:() 7f9bd5b5db50
self.myadd_curve_button: <__main__.MyButton object at 0x7f9bd5b5db50>
child: <__main__.MyButton object at 0x7f9bd5b5db50>
```

Why are the hex numbers the same when I simply print the objects, but different with the call to `id()`? How come the `is` statement is returning `False`?

I've tried printing the addresses to deduce why the `is` comparison returns `False`. I'm told that the default implementation of `__str__()` should show the same address as that returned by `id()`, in hex.